# jQuery UI dialog dynamic height and width

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQuery UI dialog with an iframe:

```
function showDialog(url, title, refresh){           
    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;
    var width = 650; height = 800;
    $('<iframe id="modalIframeId" allowtransparency="true" style="background-color:#c0c0c0;" frameborder="0"  class="ModalIFrame" src="' + url + '" />')
        .dialog({
            title: title,                
            width: width,
            height: height,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            autoResize: true,
            close: function(ev, ui) {
                if(refresh)
                    location.reload();
                else
                    $(this).close();
            },
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.7,
                background: "black"
            }
        })
        .width(width - horizontalPadding)
        .height(height - verticalPadding);  
    return false;
}
```

Is it possible to set `width` and `height` like window size?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-width) you can.

(Code added since the link does not take user directly to the correct section):

OPTION - width

Initialize the dialog with the width option specified:
Code Examples:

Invoke the close method:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" );
```

Get or set the width option, after initialization:

```
//Getter
var width = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width" );

//Setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 500 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the window width and height by

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

and use the variables in your dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

Add a

```
height: 140,
width: 140,
```

in with the rest of your options